# What's wrong with my Cmake libxml2 project?

Tags: xml, compilation, cmake, libxml2

This is my first time using C/C++, as well as CMake, so there could be lots of things wrong.

I've set up a minimal project using CMake and libxml2. It looks like this:

`xmltest/

xmltest/source/

xmltest/source/CMakeLists.txt

xmltest/source/testxml.c

xmltest/source/libxml2/

xmltest/source/libxml2/CMakeLists.txt

xmltest/source/libxml2/lots of source files...`

In `xmltest/source/CMakeLists.txt` I put:

```
PROJECT( XMLTEST )
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.8 )

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( libxml2 )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"/libxml2/include
)
```

And `xmltest/source/libxml2/CMakeLists.txt` was taken from http://epiar.net/trac/browser/Build/cmake/ThirdParty/LibXml2/CMakeLists.txt . I left it alone except for fixing `LIBXML_SRC_FOLDER`.

The rest of `xmltest/source/libxml2/` was extracted from http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxml2-sources-2.7.6.tar.gz .

I used cmake-gui to build the project in `xmltest/build/`, and it worked fine. MinGW compiled it to libxml2.a and I was proud.

Then I tried to add an executable `#include`ing libxml2.

I added this to the main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE( xmltest
    xmltest.c
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( xmltest
    xml2
)
```

and created `xmltest.c`:

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

CMake still generates it without complaining, but when compiling I get

```
fatal error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
```

I've tried a few variations on the `#include` line:

```
#include <libxml>
#include <libxml2>
#include <xml2>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml2/parser.h>
#include <xml2/parser.h>
#include "libxml2/include/libxml/parser.h"
```

but it hasn't helped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove qoutes there:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"/libxml2/include
)
```

Also make sure, that `include_directories()` invocation is done before `add_executable()` call.

Finally, make `#include` clause in your source be relative to `xmltest/source/libxml2/include`.

**EDIT:**
Okay, since it's right answer, let me explain CMake's behavior.

In CMake, there are **strings** and there are **lists**. Lists are actually strings too, but they are separated by ";".
So, `"aaa;bbb;ccc"` is a string and a list, while `"aaabbbccc"` is just a string (well it's list with single element, but it's irrelevant).

If you write `set(STR1 abc)` or `set(STR2 "abc")` you will get same strings.
But if you write `set(STR1 a b c)` you will get a list with 3 elements. It's the same as if you write `set(STR1 "a;b;c")`.

So, you faced your problem because `"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"/libxml2/include` is actually a list with two dirs. If you pass it into `include_directories()` you will get these flags: `-I${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} -I/libxml2/include` which is obviously not what you wished.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I think the quotes messed it up. I included them in case ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} has spaces, but it looks like they have to be around the entire path: "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libxml2/include" and maybe they're not even necessary.